# Populating a ComboBox with a ComboBox

Tags: java, combobox

i have a problem here, instead of items in combobox2 being replaced, it stacks. i tried to put  bookss.removeAllItems(); on top of bookss.addItem(names);   but i get an error whenever i clicked another items in the combobox1.

here's my code

```
String caa = categorys.getSelectedItem().toString();
if ("Fiction".equals(caa))
{
    String acct = categorys.getSelectedItem().toString();
    try{
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from books where category=?");
        pst.setString(1, acct);
        ResultSet rsf = pst.executeQuery();
        rsf.next();
        try{
            rsf = stmt.executeQuery("select * from BOOKS WHERE category='Fiction'");
            while(rsf.next())
            {
                String names = rsf.getString("book_title");
                bookss.addItem(names);
            }
            }catch(SQLException err){
            System.out.println(err);
        }
        }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
if ("Horror".equals(caa))
{
    String acct = categorys.getSelectedItem().toString();
    try{
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from books where category=?");
        pst.setString(1, acct);
        ResultSet tts = pst.executeQuery();
        tts.next();
        try{
            tts = stmt.executeQuery("select * from BOOKS WHERE category='Horror'");
            while(tts.next())
            {
                String names = tts.getString("book_title");
                bookss.addItem(names);
            }
            }catch(SQLException err){
            System.out.println(err);
        }
        }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you call `revalidate()` after removing and re-adding the components? When you add components to an already visible container, it's considered invalid (doc for [`invalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#invalidate())): *Marking a container invalid indicates that the container needs to be laid out. This methid is called automatically when any layout-related information changes (e.g. setting the bounds of the component, or adding the component to a container)*. Since you are adding new components to a container (your JComboBox), you gotta revalidate

Comment: i don't know what happened, but it works now

Comment: Without doing anything? Sounds like a hard-to-reproduce bug; a sign that you are not properly posting your Swing code to the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html): "*Some Swing component methods are labelled "thread safe" in the API specification; these can be safely invoked from any thread. All other Swing component methods must be invoked from the event dispatch thread. Programs that ignore this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to unpredictable errors that are difficult to reproduce.*"

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) ComboBox.getModel();
model.removeAllElements();
```